# convert unix time to date object

Tags: javascript, date, unix-timestamp

I have a `unix time` and need to get a `Date` object from it.
This code just transform the timestamp to human readable way:

```
var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
```

As a result I get `13:44:6`, for instance
but how I can create a `Date` object with time and date from it?

Comment: I'm confused, you are already creating a Date object from the timestamp.

Comment: to be clear, you want to convert "13:44:6" into a date object?

Comment: @Bob Can you explain what you mean by 'Date object'? Your first line directly does `new Date` and makes a Date object. Why do you need to convert the text back into one again. And how can the newly created date include the date if the string doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at date.js

http://www.datejs.com/

```
var datestr = "13:44:06";
var date = Date.parse(datestr,"hh:mm:ss");
alert(date);
```

This alerts a date string set to today's date, but with the time in datestr.

**NOTE**  For this to work, I needed to zero-pad the seconds.

**EDIT**

The link for date.js format specifiers is a bit buried, so here's that link if you need it:

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a *prototype function* for **Date** object to convert unix timestamp to **YYYYMMDD**.

You can edit it as you like

```
var bd = new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);
bd = bd.toYYYYMMDD();
// 1970-01-01

if ( !Date.prototype.toYYYYMMDD ) {
    ( function() {
        function pad(number) {
            var r = String(number);
            if ( r.length === 1 ) {
                r = '0' + r;
            }
            return r;
        }
        Date.prototype.toYYYYMMDD = function() {
            if(!this.getUTCDate() || this.getUTCDate() === 'NaN')
                return '1970-01-01';
            return this.getUTCFullYear()
            + '-' + pad( this.getUTCMonth() + 1 )
            + '-' + pad( this.getUTCDate() );
        };   
    }() );
};
```